# Making text box hidden in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET 3.5 and C#.

On my page I need to have a Text box that must not be visible to the user but it MUST be there when you look at the Page Source, reason being, another program called Eloqua will be looking at the page source and it must get the value of that text box.

The value of that text box will be populated based on what the user selects.

Thus, I cant set the text box property to Visible = False because then it will not be in the source HTML and I can't set the Enabled = False because I do not want the user to see the text box.

Is there some property I can use to make this text box hidden to the user but still visible in the page source?

My ASP.NET text box

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTester" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use a hidden field.

```
<asp:HiddenField id="myHiddenInput" runat="server" />
```

Use it just like a textbox.

Comment: that won't work if you need events.  The hidden field won't trigger change events.

Answer (score 15):

Try this to invisible textbox instead of server side Visible property :

```
myTextBox.Style.Add("visibility", "hidden");
// or :
myTextBox.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

Comment: hidden field couldn't get/set text in codebutt; so, this was way to go

Comment: (could be a reference to this: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/2667634/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-When-obscenity-filters-go-wrong.html)

Comment: @BenMcIntyre, then the original sentence was "hidden field couldn't get/set text in codeass"? hahahahaha

Comment: OK, maybe I'm going to have to actually say it: 'code behind'

Answer (score 9):

First thought: Can you use a hidden field? This would be much more suitable (<asp:hiddenfield ID="blah" runat="Server" /> if you want a .NET control).

If the app won't take that though you can actually just put "style='display: none;'" in the code-infront of the page. Intellisense won't like it, but it'll render just fine (EG: <asp:TextBox id="txtField" style="display: none;" runat="server" />)

Also from the codebehind you can do txtField.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none");

Or you could also just give it a CssClass "hidden" which in your CSS is defined as ".hidden { display: none;}"

The CSS class or just using a hidden field would be my recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

[Page.RegisterHiddenField](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t80197-hidden-texbox.html) or [asp:HiddenField](http://forums.asp.net/p/1073150/1570202.aspx#1570202)

Answer (score 2):

If it must be a textbox for whatever reason just hide it with css:

```
<input type="text" name="blah" style="display:none" />
```

Comment: this solved my problem, as for some reason, the text from the hidden field doesn't get retrieved. so I need to hide the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

**CSS:**

```
.hidden-div
{
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hidden-div">
    <input ... />
</div>
```

It will cause your input to be hidden, but it's gonna be visible in source code.

EDIT: Sorry, I misread it. I thought you wanted to hide an input. But it doesn't matter anyway, just replace input with basically anything.

Comment: display:none is probably more what you'd want. Visibility hidden would leave a gap in the middle of his form.

Comment: Stupid mistake, sorry. Edited :)

Answer (score 1):

By Setting Visible = "false" in server side will not render the control. You should either use `asp:Hidden` or `INPUT type="hidden"`. Other option is using CSS, by setting `display:none.`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="blah" />
```

Comment: Because I am using ASP.NET, I cant specify a type

Answer (score 0):

How about using CSS to hide a div containing the text box:

```
.hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
```

Then within your page:

```
<div class="hidden">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="hi"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This misses the concept of "hidden" and lets any code reader think that there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply,** Try to create a `CSS class` and attach it to your `TextBox` as the following:

**CSS Class Style**

```
<style>
    .Hide {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

**Textbox using `CssClass="Hide"`**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTester" runat="server" CssClass="Hide"></asp:TextBox>
```

> **Note:** you can't use validation with the `Hidden` control

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).