# How do you assign a specific NAME to a tag when using master pages?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages, google-checkout

I am using Master Pages and I am truing to dynamically add hidden text boxes on the form with the NAMEs that Google Checkout expects.

```
<input name="item_name_1" type="hidden" value="Widget #1"/>
```

Using VB.NET, I execute the following  code

```
'Name
Dim hidName As New HtmlInputHidden
hidName.ID = "item_name_" & count.ToString
hidName.Value = item
Form.Controls.Add(hidName)
```

But because I use Master Pages, the control is renamed to "ctl00$item_name_1".

```
<input name="ctl00$item_name_1" type="hidden" id="ctl00_item_name_1"
```

Note that I tried to set the Name property (hidName.Name = "item_name_" & count.ToString) and also tried to add the name to the Attributes list. This strangely had no effect on the name attribute  whatsoever. When I am not using master pages, I notice that when I set the ID property the NAME is automatically assigned the same value.

Is there a way to control the name of a dynamically added control when you are using master pages?

Answer (score 1):

`System.Web.UI.WebControls.Control` has a property called `ClientIDMode`.
Instead of `HtmlInputHidden`, you may use a `HiddenField`.

```
 'Name
Dim hidName As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField
hidName.ID = "item_name_" & count.ToString
hidName.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static
hidName.Value = item
Form.Controls.Add(hidName)
```

See [Making text box hidden in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807454/making-text-box-hidden-in-asp-net) and [HiddenField Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield(v=VS.100).aspx).

The `ClientIDMode` was introduced in the .Net Framework 4.0.
For earlier versions, an alternative could be adding a `asp:Literal`.

```
 'Name
Dim hidName As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal
hidName.Text = _
  String.Format("<input name=""item_name_{0}"" type=""hidden"" value=""{1}""/>", _
                count, item)
Form.Controls.Add(hidName)
```

Comment: ClientIDMode is only available in asp.net webforms 4.0, I believe.

Comment: @Chad Yes, it was introduced in the .Net Framework 4.0. I revised the answer to be more complete, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the simple answer is No. The more difficult answer is Yes, but not in a straightforward way. A workaround is not to try to set the property but instead define the name as an attribute:

```
Dim hidName As New HtmlInputHidden
hidName.Attributes("Name") = "item_name_" & count.ToString
hidName.Value = item
Form.Controls.Add(hidName)
```